# Bazel rules_foreign_cc error "fail("No generator set and no default is known. Please set the cmake `generator` attribute")"

Tags: bazel, freebsd, bazel-rules

I am trying to compile zlib with rules_foreign_cc and I get the following error in FreeBSD

```
"fail("No generator set and no default is known. Please set the cmake `generator` attribute")"
```

My BUILD file is

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(
        include = ["**"],
        exclude = ["*.bazel"],
    ),
)

cmake(
    name = "zlib",
    generate_args = select({
        "@platforms//os:windows": ["-GNinja"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
    targets = ["install"],
    lib_source = ":all_srcs",
    out_static_libs = select({
        "@platforms//os:windows": ["z.lib"],
        "//conditions:default": ["libz.a"],
    }),
)
```

The same file for the same zlib package compiles in Ubuntu 16 and MacOS

Any idea why it cannot find the generator and if I have to declare it explicitly under generate_args, what are the valid options?

I tried -Gcc, -Gmake, -Gcmake, but all result in unknown generator.

Comment: Are you building cmake from source or is it preinstalled on your system? If preinstalled what version is it?

Comment: From what I see here [.bazelrc](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/blob/main/third_party_libraries/cpp/zlib/.bazelrc), it seems you have rules according to the OS in use. So, your error could say that you don't have any rules for the `FreeBSD OS` pointing to a generator, hence `no generator` or no `default one` (fallback). `uname -a` and `bazel info release` could help to create what you need.

Comment: Well, just set `"//conditions:default"` to `-G"Unix Makefiles"` or `-GNinja`?

Comment: @JamesSharpe preinstalled cmake version 3.16.5

Comment: @arrowd that seems to work, so far as the error above is concerned. Now there is a failure in "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1". I suppose we have a generator, not sure if it is the correct one. Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with generator. You code compiles but doesn't link.

Comment: @arrowd It compiles with gmake on FreeBSD and it compiles under linux. So you mean it is an error with the BUILD file and not the selected generator?